# Failed to center elements with CSS GRID

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout, text-alignment

I am practicing with css grid, and I want to center some elements with justify-content: center, but it does not work, I am new to css grid and I would like to understand the error.

**Attached image, I want to center the element inside leftbar, the one with the image of home and below text**

[image: I]

CSS CODE:

```
/* Container principal */
.container {
    font-family: Arial;
    max-height: 80vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px  1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 70px minmax(300px ,85vh);
    grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar"
                        "leftbar subcontainer"
                        "leftbar subcontainer";
}
/* BARRA IZQUIERDA COLORES */
.leftbar{
background: pink;
grid-area: leftbar;

}
/* COntainer de la barra lateral izquierda */
.containerleftbar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px);
    justify-items: center;
    align-content: initial;
}
.home span img {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

HTML CODE :

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item leftbar">
            <div class="containerleftbar">
                <div class="home item-1">
                    <span>
                        <img src="hom2.png" alt="homeimg">
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="trending item-2">
                    <span>
                        <p>Trending</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="likes item-1">
                    <span>
                        <p>Likes</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item navbar" >
            <div class="containernavbar">
                NAVBAR
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item subcontainer">
            <div class="containerx2">
                CONTAINER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When putting the image of home, the text is no longer at the center, but I don't know why it is, it may be a very basic doubt, but I am new to css

Comment: `.leftbar` is aligning center, however your content inside `.home` is not centered. Either set `.home` to `width: 50%;` or set `.home` to `text-align: center;`

Comment: You are the best bro haha <3, thanks